# ERROR 1286 (42000): Unknown storage engine 'Columnstore'

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

I installed a MariaDB 10.2.15 with Columnstore 1.1.5 on a CentOS 7.5 and then I created a few InnoDB and Columnstore tables. So far so good.

I needed the root user and another one to be able to run cross-engine queries as I needed to insert-select from some InnoDB tables into some Columnstore tables. Therefore I added the following section into `/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/etc/Columnstore.xml`

```
<CrossEngineSupport>
        <Host>127.0.0.1</Host>
        <Port>3306</Port>
        <User>root</User>
        <Password/>
</CrossEngineSupport>
<CrossEngineSupport>
        <Host>127.0.0.1</Host>
        <Port>3306</Port>
        <User>someuser</User>
        <Password>somepassword</Password>
</CrossEngineSupport>
```

Strangely, from that moment I was unable to connect with `mcsmysql` as root without providing a password anymore. No, problem I said, let's set some root password.
I stopped Columnstore:

```
mcsadmin shutdownsystem
```

and then ran

```
/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

I connected as root without a password and then ran the following queries:

```
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("some-new-password") where User='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

I restarted columnstore

```
mcsadmin restartsystem
```

Of course, I updated the Columnstore.xml with the new root password.
Now I am able to connect again with root and the new password but the problem is that the Columnstore engine is not available anymore.
When I run `show create table sometable`, where `sometable` is a Columnstore table which used to work just fine, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1286 (42000): Unknown storage engine 'Columnstore'
```

And when I run `show engines`, indeed, the Columnstore is missing in that list. Basically, I can't use the Columnstore tables for anything.

Any idea of what could have caused this and how could I enable the Columnstore engine?

Comment: I think that the main guilty here is `mysqld_safe`, that should have rewrite some configurations to their default state...you know that you can connect to `mariadb` from a terminal with just `mysql -uroot -p`, so there is no need to use `mysqld_safe`...anyway, the best thing to do is to purge and install again columnstore.

Comment: @Hackerman, yeah, I hoped that I'll find a solution to fix the issue but I ended-up reinstalling everything.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it must be `--datadir` set by `mysqld_safe` since here is an ps output that shows both `mysqld_safe` and `mysqld`:

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql//bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/db --pid-file=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/db/62f59fb5c00b.pid --ledir=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql//bin

/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql//bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/ --datadir=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/db --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/db/62f59fb5c00b.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/db/62f59fb5c00b.pid --socket=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

Comment: If you mean datadir setting from the my.cnf file, then no, mysqld_safe didn't change that. I reinstalled everything in the meantime though.